# vite: No loader is configured for ".html" files

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, ejs, vite

Trying to build a simple Vite project and every thing is right, but when I add a library(it's a privite library in my company so I call it `ui-modal` here), getting an error

```json
✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".html" files: node_modules/ui-modal/src/template/toast.html

    node_modules/ui-modal/es5/Toast.js:20:44:
      20 │ ...fault(require("../src/template/toast.html"));
         ╵                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

10:22:45 AM [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/ui-modal/es5/Toast.js:20:44: ERROR: No loader is configured for ".html" files: node_modules/ui-modal/src/template/toast.html
```

I checked the `ui-modal` library and find out that it compiled with `webpack`, but there is only `text-loader` for `.html` files， so it has been relying on the user's webpack configuration to process this html file. The code corresponding to the error is as follows

**node_modules/ui-modal/es5/Toast.js**

```js
var _toast = _interopRequireDefault(require("../src/template/toast.html"));
```

**node_modules/ui-modal/src/template/toast.html**

```html
<div class="ui-toast-box _u-modal-box <%if(data.id){%> ui-toast-<%=data.id%> <%}%> <%if(data.animation){%> ui-toast-animation <%}%>">
    <p class="ui-toast"><%=data.content%></p>
</div>
<div class="ui-dialog-mask<%if(data.duration && !data.captureEvt){%> ui-dialog-mask-noevent<%}%>" <%if(!data.withMask){%> style="opacity: 0;" <%}%> ></div>
```

I know that if I used webpack, I could solve this with `html-loader`, so I tried to use `html-loader` manually, but failed because lack of webpack context in vite

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If they're ejs files rename all your `.html` files `.ejs`