# No loader is configured for ".html" files: index.html Vitejs

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vite

Greetings I have problem. I am using Visual studio 2022 and created two projects there for one solution. One for back-end (ASP.NET) and the second one for fron-end (vuejs and vite). So here starts the problem. I used npm create vue@3 command to create vue project. And  its launched fine , but when I did same thing in folder of front-end in my sln project vite throws error what it can not find index.html file

```bash
Error:   Failed to scan for dependencies from entries:
  D:/Projects/C#/DAINIS/vueapp/index.html

  X [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".html" files: index.html

    <stdin>:1:7:
      1 │ import "D:/Projects/C#/DAINIS/vueapp/index.html"
        ╵        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    at failureErrorWithLog (D:\Projects\C#\DAINIS\vueapp\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1638:15)
    at D:\Projects\C#\DAINIS\vueapp\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1050:25
    at runOnEndCallbacks (D:\Projects\C#\DAINIS\vueapp\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1473:45)
    at buildResponseToResult (D:\Projects\C#\DAINIS\vueapp\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1048:7)
    at D:\Projects\C#\DAINIS\vueapp\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1060:9
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at requestCallbacks.on-end (D:\Projects\C#\DAINIS\vueapp\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1059:54)
    at handleRequest (D:\Projects\C#\DAINIS\vueapp\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:725:19)
    at handleIncomingPacket (D:\Projects\C#\DAINIS\vueapp\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:747:7)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (D:\Projects\C#\DAINIS\vueapp\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:675:7)
```

Just in case I did not changed project it is as is.
[Project structure](https://imgur.com/0i7ptC8)
[Error dump example](https://imgur.com/HACwXPY)

I tried solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73849238/vite-no-loader-is-configured-for-html-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67330947/vite-cannot-handle-xxx-html-files) in stack overflow but still no luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the `#` symbol in your file path

```
D:/Projects/C#/DAINIS/vueapp/
```

I don't know the technical reason why this causes it to fail, but if you remove it, the project should run.